# googlecl Comnmand line: contain double and single quotes in the title

Tags: string, command-line, quotes, double-quotes

Any [googlecl](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) user here?

I am using the latest version of googlecl and poython 2.5.

The title of my post is `"Moon" - Official Trailer`. What should I do?

The following code wont work:

```
$ google blogger post --title ""Moon" - Official Trailer" "command line posting"
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My shell is # bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"; echo -ne "\007"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the enclosed quotes

like that
google blogger post --title "\"Moon\" - Official Trailer" "command line posting"

Comment: Another option would be to use single-quotes instead of double quotes, assuming you title doesn't actually include single quotes.